# Does $\int_2^{\infty}\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)/\ln\left(x\right) \, dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\displaystyle\int _2^{\infty }\:\:\left(\frac{\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}\right)dx$$
Hi, Can anyone tell me how to start to answer for questions of divergence or convergence what it has complete value?

I have no idea on where to start. No need for a solution or anything of the sort, just what am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Of course one point to check is $x \to \infty$.  Looking at the $\ln(x)$ in the denominator, we should also check whether it vanishes in $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: Yea ofcourse, checking limits of boundrys, that I did, but something else? the problem is the complete value.

Comment: Is $\llcorner (x)\lrcorner$ the floor function? If so, then try using `$\lfloor\rfloor$`

Comment: @Gary Oh thanks, I couldnt find something similliar. Thanks!! 
About Tyma, yea, floor function, and thanks.